# Como fazer conexões a um php funcionar em background no Android

Tags: php, java, android

Eu tenho um pequeno *app* de *chat* que faz login e envia mensagens pro servidor através de **php** + ***JSON***, mas cada **query** trava o aplicativo por uns meio segundo, o que é realmente chato.

Ouvi dizer algo chamado **Backgroundworker**, mas não sei exatamente como funciona isso.

Esse é meu codigo:

```
    EditText campoLogin = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.campo_de_login);
    EditText campoSenha = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.campo_de_senha);
    Conectar Conn = new Conectar("http://meusite.com/chat/login.php?login=" + campoLogin.getText() + "&senha=" + campoSenha.getText() );

    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(Conn.response);
    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(0);
    id = (String) object.get("id");
    nome = (String) object.get("nome");
```

*Precisaria fazer com que esse processo não travasse, e funcionasse em background...*

Comment: O que faz parar a query, o php ou o java do android?

Comment: O Android consulta uma pagina em php que a mesma consulta o BD e é recebido no Android. Funciona bem, mas trava.

Comment: Onde é que voce tem o servidor? Tem ligação a rede boa? E o android? Eu envio ficheiros XML e é relativamente rápido. Trava mesmo ou demora tempo?

Comment: O servidor é Bem Rápido o problema é que o app trava quando esta conectando ate receber a mensagem, ou seja se eu fizer um loop que atualizasse o tempo todo fazendo diversas conexoes entao o app iria travar sem parar.....

Comment: Ah isso, tens de por o teu serviço no android como um [service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode criar uma subclass da classe [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

```
private class LoginAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean> {
    protected String doInBackground(String... parametros) {
       String campoLogin = parametros[0];
       String campoSenha = parametros[1];
       Conectar Conn = new Conectar("http://meusite.com/chat/login.php?login=" + campoLogin + "&senha=" + campoSenha );

       JSONArray array = new JSONArray(Conn.response);
       JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(0);
       id = (String) object.get("id");
       nome = (String) object.get("nome");
       return nome != null;
 }

   protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progresso) {
       // Mostre uma barra de carregamento de acordo com o progresso.
   }

   protected void onPostExecute(Boolean login) {
       showDialog("Login com sucesso: " + login);
   }
}
```

Comment: É melhor com service, ter o serviço sempre a correr...

Comment: Usar Service é outra forma de fazer, porém é mais complicado e é indicado para tarefas que irão executar por mais tempo em plano de fundo. A idéia de um Service é a execução continua de alguma tarefa no plano de fundo. Para a execução de apenas uma tarefa, prefere-se a AsyncTask.

Comment: Sim mas pelo que percebi aqui vai ficar sempre a espera de mensagens.

Comment: Talvez na parte de mensagens sim, porém o código postado fala do login na aplicação, executado apenas uma vez.

Comment: Talvez o exemplo de login nao tenha sido uma boa ideia,  reamente eu tava pensando em usar diversas veses pra atualizar o chat... Mas a ideia do amigo acima parece promissora, nao poderia resolver o meu provlema?

Comment: Eu criei uma nova classe e coloquei o seguinte codigo acima, depois ao invez de usar `Conectar Conn = new Conectar("http://meusite.com/chat/login.php?login=" + campoLogin + "&senha=" + campoSenha );` eu estou usando um parametro **website** assim:     `protected Boolean doInBackground(String... parametros) {
       String website = parametros[0];
       Conectar Conn = new Conectar(website);
       resposta = Conn.response;` Funciona bem quando eu chamo essa classe mais ainda sim continua travando do mesmo jeito.