# Problemas com a AsyncTask travar o aplicativo

Tags: android, background-services

Eu estou desenvolvendo um *chat online* que deveria atualizar sozinho o tempo todo, o problema é que cada consulta trava o aplicativo por uns meio segundos. Eu já havia feito uma pergunta parecida em: [Como fazer conexões a um php funcionar em background no Android](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16473/como-fazer-conexoes-a-um-php-funcionar-em-background-no-android) mas não era exatamente o que eu queria.

Eu preciso que **as páginas não travassem o app em cada consulta**. Já ouvi falar sobre *backgroundWoker* e [Service](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/service/android-service-example/) mas sinceramente não tenho a menor ideia do que eu posso estar fazendo de errado.

Estou utilizando MySQL+PHP+JSON.

Esse é meu código:

```
package com.Dannark.livechat;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

class Connect extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response;
        String responseString = null;
        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(uri[0]));
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                out.close();
                responseString = out.toString();
            } else{
                //Closes the connection.
                response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            //TODO Handle problems..
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //TODO Handle problems..
        }
        return responseString;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Log.e("-- MYSQL --",result);
        //Do anything with response..
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** E estou interagindo a clase **connect** Com a classe **Conectar** dessa maneira:

```
package com.Dannark.livechat;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.Log;

public class Conectar {

    String response;
    int status;

    public Conectar(String website){
        //First - send request to server
        AsyncTask<String,String,String> task;
        String uri = website;       //  www.meusite.com/get_chat/?room=10


        try {
            task = new Connect().execute(uri);
            response = task.get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

}
```

E finalmente a classe `conectar` desta maneira:

```
Conectar Conn = new Conectar("http://animesslife.engine001.com/chat/login.php?login=" + campoLogin.getText() + "&senha=" + campoSenha.getText() );
Log.i("-RESPOSTA-",Conn.response); //Conn.response seria a resposta no decodificada em JSON
```

Deveria eu usar outro método ao invés deste?

Comment: como é que você está interagindo com a classe "Connect"? Aparentemente não estou vendo nada de errado com a AsyncTask, exceto o de não está fechando os recursos apropriadamente em um bloco "finally".

Comment: Adicionei algumas informações...

Comment: Adicionei a resposta. Estou respondendo do meu smartphone, daí não dá pra colocar o código exemplo, mas espero que pegue a idéia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A AsyncTask foi feita para você executar o código "pesado" no método **doInBackground()** e o código de UI (atualizar a tela) no método **onPostExecute()** o que você tá fazendo ao executar esse método **get()** é executar uma operação pesada de forma síncrona na MainThread, o que faz 'travar' pois a Main Thread fica ocupada com a operação.

O que você deve fazer é apenas chamar o método execute(), e dentro do **onPostExecute()** vc receberá o resultado da operação pesada como parâmetro (o retorno do método **doInBackground()** e poderá atualizar a tela dentro. Ou seja, no **onPostExecute()** vc irá fazer algo do tipo: *textView.setText(dataResult)*

Tem exemplo de uso aqui: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Ahh eu entendi cara, poxa foi bem legal sua explicação... Teria so como vc me mostrar um exemplo (quando vc tiver no seu pc) baseado no meu código para que eu possa ter certeza do que estou fazendo? :) Pra mim definir logo a resposta como aceita?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html olha o código que tem nessa página.

Comment: Ei valeu mesmo cara... :)

Comment: E se fosse o caso de eu retornar um valor da onPostExecute(), nao gostaria de digitar o camando textView.setText(result) la dentro...

Comment: não dá pra fazer isso, pois o comportamento da AsyncTask, como o próprio nome diz é assincrono e o método onPostExecute() é o callback final...o que você pode fazer é repassar a chamada para um outro metodo...mas se você usar a AsyncTask não dá pra evitar o onPostExecute().